# Ubuntu 12.10 Fresh Install Blank Screen Issue With Gateway Nv7802u Laptop

Tags: unity, 12.10, intel-graphics

Before flagging this question as a possible duplicate, and saying that I have not done any research, give me a moment to explain the issue. I have done search after search on Google, on ask Ubuntu, and ubuntuforums, I have read about solution to the problems that were similar to mine but I still have not solved the problem. Ever since Ubuntu 10.04 I believe I cannot use my laptop monitor, it just boots up blank and even while installation, I know it is probably driver related. This probably the reason why I haven't used Ubuntu in a while and I would like to give it another try. I obviously don't want to get a new laptop although getting a new one might solve the problem. It isn't that old either and it runs very well for its age.

## My Specs

- 4 gb RAM
- 64-bit Intel Core 2 Duo
- 500 gb SATA hardisk
- Intel GMA 4500 (Integrated Graphics)
- Gateway Nv7802u

## What I have Tried

- nomodeset (It freezes after the screen says low graphics detected)
- I have tried looking for additional hardware drivers none available.
- I have tried numerous settings like apci_backlight=vendor and nothing ever changes its like the solutions I have been reading aren't doing nothing.

It is not hardware issue because Windows can run fine including the new Windows 8. I also had the same issue with Fedora a while back when I used it but I fixed it by finding the drivers for my graphics card.

## My Question

How can I fix this, I already installed it and clearly I can use my laptop if hooked to an external monitor via VGA but my laptop just stays blank or pretty much dim to the point that you cannot see anything. It could it be that Unity is the problem. I like Unity but if it means using Gnome then fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I fixed it by pressing the brightness key on my laptop. Which was strange because yesterday it didn't do anything. But I also found out that it was a brightness issue and that Ubuntu apparently interprets my brightness keys the wrong way. So lets say I press Fn+Up it dims instead of brightening. Kind of strange but I can live with it until I get a new machine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

#### SCREEN BRIGHTNESS

type in the terminal:

```
sudo sed "s/\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\)\"\"/\1\"acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor\"/" /etc/default/grub -i
```

then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before.

When at the *Low Graphics Detected* window, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Login with your account, and type

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

It has fixed the problem for me in the past. Good luck.

Comment: Nope tried what you did and I saw a wired blue rectangles on the screen with the caret blinking in the top left corner. No shell login. Thanks for suggestion.